# Can't find g++ in Software Center

Tags: installation, software-center, g++

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 and I tried to install `g++`. Unfortunately I did not find it in the Software Center. In the sources list the boxes for universe and main are checked. Any suggestions or hints?

Edit: As said below: I think the problem is that the Software Center needs some time to refresh the software sources. I did nothing and after appr. one hour every was available.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to install the package [build-essential](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/build-essential) [image: Install build-essential]
 that will bring in the compilers `gcc`, `g++` and other tools for development, like `gdb` and `make`.

Comment: It works now. I do not know why, but suddenly the search result showed the correct packages.

Comment: The current g++ is 4.6.1

Comment: I think the problem is that the Software Center needs some time to refresh the software sources. I did nothing and after appr. one hour every was available.

Comment: You can force the sources to refresh in Update Manager (press `Check`) - the results should show in Software Center as well, they use the same packages. Be worth a try next time :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

`sudo apt-get install g++`

this will help you install it via the Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]